# PosgresSQL - sql to generate Json from multiple tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

Postgres V13

trying to understand how can i generate Json base relational data in PS(simple tables),
Im writing a tool which generate SQL for generating Json based on relational data ,
The user provide mapping rules - which maps each Json field to the table.field and the tool build the SQL which provide the data in required json format .

for example for very similiar json I need to create on Ps,
on Oracle DB(Oracle version >12.2)
I get it by running:

```
SELECT JSON_OBJECT ('FIRST_NAME' VALUE TO_CHAR(CUSTOMER.FIRST_NAME),
'concatDeails' VALUE  JSON_OBJECT ('conctant_name' VALUE TO_CHAR(CUSTOMER.FIRST_NAME) || TO_CHAR(CUSTOMER.LAST_NAME)),
'Payments' VALUE (SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG  ( JSON_OBJECT ('payment_id' VALUE PAYMENT.payment_id, 
'amount' VALUE payment.amount
)
 RETURNING VARCHAR2(32000) )
FROM PAYMENT WHERE PAYMENT.CUSTOMER_ID = CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_ID )format  json )  JSON_OUT 
FROM CUSTOMER
```

And there is one--> many relation between customer to payment tables,
So for Postgres I have 3 tables:
customer(address_id is uniq key)
address (address_id is pk)
payment (customer can multiple payments)

The json should look as:

```json
{
  "first_name": "Jared", 
  "last_name": "Ely", 
  "concatDeails":{ "conctant_name": "Jared Ely"},
  "Address":{"city": "NY" ,"Zip": 123123},
  "Payments":[{"payment_id": 1,"amount":100 , "credit": null }]
 
}
```

I know how to create each block but from some reason ,
Not able to get all of them in single query .

for getting the first_name and concatDeails:

```
select json_build_object('first_name'  , customer.first_name ,'concatDeails' ,json_build_object('last_nam1e' , customer.last_name||customer.last_name)) 
                         from customer
```

Address dict:

```
select   
    json_build_object('address' ,json_build_object('city_id' , address.city_id, 'postal_code' ,address.postal_code) )
                         from address ;
```

payment list object:

```
select jsonb_build_array(json_build_object('payment_id'  , payment.payment_id ,'amount' , payment.amount ,"credit" , payment.credit)) from payment ;
```

When i try to combine them into single query ,
getting failed :

```
elect json_build_object('first_name'  , customer.first_name ,'concatDeails' ,json_build_object('last_nam1e' , customer.last_name||customer.last_name),
                            (select     json_build_object('address' ,json_build_object('city_id' , address.city_id, 'postal_code' ,address.postal_code) )
                             from address where address.address_id=customer.address_id),
                             (select jsonb_build_array(json_build_object('payment_id'  , payment.payment_id ,'amount' , payment.amount))
                             from payment where payment.customer_id=customer.customer_id)               
                             )
                             from customer;

ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
SQL state: 21000
```

Actually even if I try to combine address and  customer  I'm getting error:
https://sqlize.online/sql/psql13/c495c4468aa8a9af897f28c5762c9035/

Can some1 explain how i can combine them all as single query
In most simple way?
second , How can I display "null" in the json where no value return    (see in the example Paymnet-->credit) ?

Comment: Please provide your tables structure and sample data [mre]

Comment: I mean it's because you have more then one payment for customer

Answer (score 0):

Please look next solution:

```
select 
    json_build_object(
      'first_name', customer.first_name ,
      'concatDeails', json_build_object(
            'conctant_name', customer.first_name || ' ' || customer.last_name
      ),
      'Address', json_build_object(
            'city', address.city,
            'Zip',  address.Zip
        ),
      'Payments', payment
    ) 
 from customer
 left join address on address.customer_id = customer.id
 left join (
    select 
        customer_id, 
        array_agg(json_build_object(
            'payment_id', payment_id, 'amount', amount, 'credit', credit
        )) 
    from payment 
    group by customer_id
 ) payment on payment.customer_id = customer.id;
```

[Look here PostgreSQL fiddle](https://sqlize.online/sql/psql13/860b4e3269b0a1dfae90308c0849ab0f/)

Comment: Thanks Slava ,I understand your solution ,but im looking for the simplistic solution to achieve that , the reason is I'm writing a tool which dynamically generate the sql for generating the json  - user provide some mapping rule and the tool builds the SQL , is there alternative way writing that query ? without those left join (i will provide more details in the post)

Comment: Post updated with an example how i done same on Oracle

Answer (score 0):

After lot of trials I manage to get this work ,
for me it looks more coherent way ,
In addition , find more than one way to manage nulls

So if you got here and need to build a json with specific structure and data coming from different tables , this can help:

```sql
select row_to_json(customer) as customer_json
from (
  select customer.first_name "first_name" ,null as "test_null",
    ( json_build_object('concatDeails' , customer.first_name||customer.last_name)  ) as "concatDeails",
    (select json_agg(payment)
     from (
         select payment.payment_id "payment_id" ,payment.amount  "amount" from payment 
         where payment.customer_id=customer.customer_id
     ) payment
     ) as payment ,
    (select row_to_json(address)
     from (
         select address.address "address_details",CASE WHEN address.phone IS  NULL THEN 'NO_PHONE' ELSE address.phone  END as "phone_no_null",
          address.phone as "phone", COALESCE(address.phone, 'NO_PHONE') as "phone_coalesce"          
         from address  where address.address_id=customer.address_id
      ) address
    ) as address
    from customer as customer where customer_id=2 ) customer;
```

[image]